# How to auto-backup PostgreSQL database to a drive

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, automation, database-backups

I working on Python-Flask application that using PostgreSQL as database.
Now for secure things, I want to make daily auto-backup my database to a drive such a Google-Drive or DropBox or such any drive with the same function.

Is there any example code or source to learn which is using Python-Flask to do that..?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [package](https://github.com/cuducos/alchemydumps), it seems resolve my cases in this question.